# Detecting mime Type (CSV) in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, csv, mime-types, php-5.4

How I detect mime Type (CSV) in PHP 5.4?

Will I have enough simple PHP, do I need some library? Unfortunately, what I do not try, it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this post. Maybe it'll be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181201/using-php-to-check-mime-type-of-file-uploaded-via-form

Comment: "Call to undefined function finfo_open()". But thx :)

Comment: @JarosławOsmólski http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I have no impact on server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your php.ini file and check that the fileinfo.so or php_fileinfo.dll is activated (depending on your platform and version).

There should be a line similar to

```
extension=fileinfo.so
```

in your php.ini file

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I have no impact on server configuration.

Comment: Than you can try using fgetcsv($file) and print it out if it returns false than you know its not a csv file

Comment: fgetcsv() open JPG file as text